# How can I setup a GitHub Branch Naming Rule

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a GitHub Repo and I would like to set up some branch naming rules.
More specifically, I want to enforce a template for all branches, something like feature/ID_Feature-description, same for bug fixes bugfix/ID-Bugfix-description.
I don't want people to be able to create a branch that does not respect the pattern mentioned above.

Is there a way for doing this?

Comment: try this https://itnext.io/using-git-hooks-to-enforce-branch-naming-policy-ffd81fa01e5e

Comment: It works like a charm. Now I just need to set up my own Regex Expressions and it should be fine.
Thank you so much for your time!